# Range of numbers supported in operators

Tags: c++

I was working on some max range of value that C++'s == operator can  compare.
Program which actually deal with numbers ranging from 0 to 9×10<sup>19</sup>, supplied by the user.

Let 9×10<sup>9</sup> be the maximum value that user supplies.

```
if( x == y ) { cout << "x and y are equal"; }
```

So, will the operator `==` be able to compare that much huge range of value?

Comment: Integers or floats?

Comment: @Rotem no no.... the user can enter a no. that may be that much huge. It is up to us, that what data type to be considered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are misleading. `operator==` will always be able to work with any value held in the operands. It can also be defined for user-defined types, including classes that can represent larger numbers than the built-in types. This means that `operator==`, when defined, will work.

If your program fails to hold a user provided value, it will be at the moment it is assigned to `x` or `y`. If their types do not have the range to hold the number given by the user, it will be truncated or your program might fail, depending on how you get your numbers. In any case, when the statement `x == y` is evaluated, `operator==` will work with the values held by `x` and `y` regardless of whether they hold the values you thought  they would.

Comment: How's my answer misleading regarding that? I exactly said _"it depends on the types of operands"_?

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong but it is insufficient. "Depends on the types of the operands" could be any value that is a function of the type of operand and it does not indicate the actual answer, that every value of the operand is valid for `operator==`. It does not clearly indicate to OP that if a problem exists with the range, it is guaranteed to not be `operator==`'s fault.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your variable type can contain that much big number (like long long int, long double etc.), '==' does its job. It is not about '==' operator, just be careful your number is in range of your variable to eliminate bad results.

Edit:

> - "Range" for floating point numbers isn't just what this answer implies. – @StoryTeller

So it is better not to use '==' directly for floating numbers.

But:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x{5.5};
    float y{5.5};
    if(x==y) cout<<"As expected"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o a.out 
./a.out 
As expected
```

The problem mentioned was that, when i change floats in this code to:

```
float x{5.5666666};
float y{5.56666665};
```

Code also says they are equal.

Comment: `==` does the job as well for any implementation of a `BigInteger` class. It has nothing to do with the operator itself. So your answer is misleading, if not wrong.

Comment: @user0042 isnt it same thing with my answer?

Comment: Okay, so summing up, as long as the number lies in the range of datatype, == operator can easily perform it's task... Is that what u mean @ssovukluk

Comment: @kislay1812 yes

Comment: @kislay1812 - "Range" for floating point numbers isn't just what this answer implies.

Answer (score 1):

Which range of numbers is supported with the `==` or other operators totally depends on the types of the operands.

If you have intrinsic types as operands you can have a look at [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to explore what are the specific number limits on your specific system.

Anyways the `==` and other operators can be overloaded for e.g. a `BigNumber` class that is able to deal with numbers beyond the intrinsic limits.

---

Note that comparing floating point numbers with `==` rarely works as intended, since it's unlikely they will have exact numbers as result of multiple calculations. The example for [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) shows how floating point numbers can be compared for *almost equality*.

Comment: @user0042 I tried doing             float x=5,y=5;                        if(x==y)                                 cout<<true;                                 else cout<<false;  And mysteriously, it produced false... Why so??

Comment: @kislay1812 Read the second part of my answer, and go to the link for `std::numeric_limits::epsilon` to understand.

Comment: @kislay1812 That shouldn't happen. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @kislay1812 your float example should not happen. I added example code and its output please check it.

Comment: @ssovukluk when we supply integer to a floating variable, then the == operator misbehaves

Comment: @ssovukluk I suggest you to edit {5.5 } to {5} and run your code. The flow of control may move to else block

Comment: @kislay1812 I cannot reproduce the behavior of your specific example. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f441f462e7f6d9e5) please.

Comment: @user0042 may be the version I am using is old, so some obsolete result was happening.